# How to convert from Binary to Decimal

Tags: java, binary, decimal

I recently have took help on how to finish this code, but I got another huge error I don't know how to fix.  It is telling me to utilize the numbers variable but I do in one of the first lines of code.  Can you guys please help.  Thanks!

```
public static int binToDec(int i)
{
    int[] numbers;//initialize variable
    int f = 4;
    String iString = "" + i;
    int result = 0;
    int length = iString.length();
    int power;
    for(power = iString.length(); power>=0;power--)
    {
    while(f == length && f >= 0)
    {

        numbers[power] = iString.charAt(power)^power;
    }

    length--;
    f--;
    }
    for(int g = 0; g <= numbers.length; g++)//double check constraints
    {
        result = numbers[g] = numbers[power];
    }

        return result;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked up what _initialize variable_ means?

Comment: Yes, I have tried almost everything, but nothing is working for me

Comment: You didn't initialize `numbers`; you only declared it.

Comment: how do I declare it?

Comment: Please post the error, this is broad at the moment

Comment: You're misreading all the guidance.

Comment: it is giving me errors at all of the numbers variables.

Comment: I have editted my answer @BlakeWhite, I thought you were notified of that. have a look at this.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error because numbers has been declared but not initialized.  Try

numbers = new int[length];

after you set length.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Integer.parseInt(binaryNumber, 2)` method to directly convert any binary number into decimal number, where binary is `String`.

Use this code, which is more efficient to convert binary numbers into decimal numbers.

```
public static int binaryToDecimal(String binary) {
    int decimal = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++) {
        int digit = new Integer(binary.charAt(binary.length() - i - 1) + "");
        decimal += digit * Math.pow(2, i);
    }
    return decimal;
}
```

Comment: Let me know if you only want to do it your way.